# unity3d An object reference is required to access non-static member `CoinAudio.Audiosrc'

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

as the title said I am trying to call Run() in this code

```
CoinAudio.Run();
```

and this is this Script of Run()

```
public class CoinAudio : MonoBehaviour {
    private AudioSource Audiosrc;

    void Start () {
           Audiosrc=GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public static void Run () {
         Audiosrc.Play();

    }}
```

and when I try to call Run() to run sound it gives me this error 
**An object reference is required to access non-static member `CoinAudio.Audiosrc'**
any solution, please 
and Please do not tell me the question is repeated my problem is totally different it is right that it has the same name but not the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static keyword from the "Run" method:

```
     private AudioSource Audiosrc;

    void Start () {
       Audiosrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
       Run ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Run () {
         Audiosrc.Play();
    }
```

Comment: did not work as I said I'm trying to call Run from another C# Script ex when i touch the coin it calls Run from AudioManger Script, not in the same script

Comment: there are tow C# script one call Coin and the another call CoinAudio

Answer (score 0):

So you have a CoinAudio class and an AudioManager class

but you are calling CoinAudio.Run() will not work as the compiler said you need to create an instance  variable:

So in the AudioManager if the CoinAudio script is attached to a GameObject Called MyAudio you could write something like:

```
GameObject g;

void Start () 
{
    g = GameObject.Find("MyAudio").GetComponent<CoinAudio>();
    g.Run();

    //NOT CoinAudio.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `AudioSource` a static member of `CoinAudio`.

```
public class CoinAudio : MonoBehaviour {
    private static AudioSource Audiosrc;

    void Start () {
       Audiosrc=GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public static void Run () {
        Audiosrc.Play();
    }
}
```